# SQL for a specific date in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle table with a DATE field, called UTC_DT.  If I do the following query, I get proper results:

```sql
select *
from   t_table
where  trunc(UTC_DT) = to_date('20200406000000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

But no result if I set some hour/min like in the following:

```sql
select *
from   t_table
where  trunc(UTC_DT) = to_date('20200406182000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

Shouldn't this work as we convert both side to a date without time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem confused between data types; perhaps you have worked in a different database environment in the past, with different data types for "dates" and "times".

Oracle's **`date`** data type has a misleading name - it should be called "date-time" because it **always** includes a time component. `to_date()` converts from **string** to date, and the result **always** has a time component. Even when you convert a string like `'20200406'` with format model `'yyyymmdd'`, with no time-of-day components; the default of `'000000'` for `'hh24miss'` is added automatically. `to_date` does ***not*** truncate from "date-time" to "date" as you seem to expect (presumably without time component - which may exist in other database products, but not in Oracle).

Comment: mmm...  If Oracle date type has a time component, it is even not shown when you select the data in SQL Dev as I see only '20-04-06' for that column.  So, I guess I have to convert my input to have trunc(utc_dt) = to_date('20200406', 'YYYYMMDD')?

Comment: @Danuc You can set the default date and time display format in the SQL Developer preference settings. Also, the simplest way of writing date literals is like `date '2020-04-06'` (format YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: "Yes" to the last part. As to what is "shown when you select data in SQL Dev" - that applies to selecting data in ANY user interface (SQL\*Plus, Toad, etc.) That is controlled by you, or by defaults if you don't control specifically. In SQL Dev you can either use the menus to change what is displayed for dates (for example 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') or you can issue a SQL statement like `alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'` (or whatever format you need). YOU control that, not Oracle and not the user interface.